# How to inscrease the max socket connections on linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, sockets, websocket

I build a socket server with node-lws(the js api of lightweightsocket written with c), the server code:

```
var lws = require('lws');
var server = new lws.Server({ port: 8000 });
var con = 0;
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    con++;
    console.log(con);
});
```

The following is the client with websocket and Promise:

```
var max = 50000;
var num = 1;
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
function it(){
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var client = new WebSocketClient();
            client.on('connect', function(connection) {
                    console.log("connected to warshou:" + num);
                    resolve();
            });
            client.connect('ws://localhost:8000/');
    });
    promise.then(function (message) {
            num++;
            if(num <= max){
                    it();
            }
    },function (error) {
            //console.log(error);
    });
}
it();
```

I run the server and client both on the same linux.
I just want to know how many connections can the server allow.
Now I run the code and the connections are 4080;

Then I make the following changes:

```
ulimit -HSn 102400
```

and append the following to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
* soft nofile 102400
* hard nofile 102400
```

and append the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
echo 3000000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max
sysctl -p
```

I restart the server and client, the connections can up to 28233
why it cannot up to 50000, current memory has 70% unused?

Answer (score 1):

Check the range of local port by following command.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

You may see two numbers, lower bound and upper bound of local port.

Usually, initial setting of the range is from 32768 to 61000 those gives 28233 varieties of port numbers.

You may be able to change lower bound to 11001 for getting 50000 connections.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now I can get 50000 connections! But what should I do if I wanna get the connections as many as possible, like one million? (Suppose th memory is enough, my server got 64G), looking forward for your reply! @fumu-7